# Python Pywallet give error in .exe made by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make my python bitcoin wallet go to exe by pyinstaller but when i run this and try to create new wallet i get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "btcwallet.py", line 111, in <module>
  File "btcwallet.py", line 80, in menu
  File "btcwallet.py", line 47, in save_wallet
  File "btcwallet.py", line 40, in generate_wallet
  File "pywallet\wallet.py", line 13, in generate_mnemonic
  File "pywallet\utils\ethereum.py", line 1321, in master_key_from_entropy
  File "mnemonic\mnemonic.py", line 47, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mistr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI35242\\mnemonic\\wordlist/english.txt'
[2548] Failed to execute script 'btcwallet' due to unhandled exception!
```

Solution:
I had to use this command: `pyinstaller --onefile --collect-all mnemonic --hidden-import mnemonic btcwallet.py`

Comment: The error message is fairly clear about what the problem is. The likely cause is that your pyinstaller config needs to include that text file into the executable. Pyinstaller doesn't (and can't) know about data files without some help.

Comment: Yes i understand the error but i don't know how to fix it. That's why i'm asking for help

Comment: See the `pyinstaller` documentation for instructions on how to set up a `.spec` file. That is how you tell `pyinstaller` about needed data files that you want included in the `.exe`. There is also a very helpful section of the `pyinstaller` documentation called *When things go wrong.* There are quite a few things that can go wrong, so you will need to work through it.

Comment: I know that i need to include this file but when i go to this directory there is no such a file so pywallet must create it for temporary time and delete it after use